# My Robot Status textboxes can not be seen to change colour using await function

Tags: c#, asp.net, async-await

I am trying to impose a 2 second delay to allow the user to see textboxes representing Robot status change colour from Red to Green for example. I am using C# and ASP.NET in a web application. It seems to be skipping a lot of the stuff without showing it to the user ie each individual step. What seems to be the problem? Please see the code below:

```
if (checkHaveEnoughChips())
{
//txtMessageBox.Text = "Theres enough chips";
                    txtCurrentOp.Text = "Robot 1 placed tray on Lazy Susan.";
                    txtRobot1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                    await wait();
                    currentTray.trayPlaced = false;
                    txtRobot1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                    txtCurrentOp.Text = "Robot 2 Assembling Chips.";
                    txtRobot2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                    await wait();

                    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                        availableChips.colour[i] = availableChips.colour[i] - currentTray.colour[i];
                    txtCurrentOp.Text = "Robot 2 has assembled chips";
                    displayAvailableChips();
                    trayDone();
                    txtRobot2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                }


 //********************************************
   protected async Task wait()
    {
        await Task.Delay(2000);
    }
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a huge misconception of how things work with web applications.

I assume you're wroking with **ASP.NET Web Forms**. The "controls" you work with are server side representations of what will be rendered to the web browser.

All that code is running on the server and, when it's done, it will render an HTML+CSS+JS page to the web browser.

**ASP.NET Web Forms**, has huge benefits, but a clear definition of where on the HTTP side of things you are is not one of them. You might want to look into **ASP.NET MVC** for a clearer separation from client and server side.

You might also want to look into client JS frameworks like AngularJS, KnocoutJS, React and such for client side code.

You might also want to look into SignalR for server notifications to the client page.

Comment: Thanks for nothing Paulo Morgado. I get what you are saying and understand it perfectly, so what you are saying is all the backend code executes and then at the end displays the front end web page, thus the reason why I see the background colour of the robot status as red meaning it did not change, when in fact all that code did execute only in the background without the front end page being updated until the closing bracket. So then in plane english the next question is how do I get it to show the changes in the front end page so I can see them???

Comment: In almost 4 months, this is the only reply to your question and, somehow, it's my fault you don't know the basics of web development.